# obtaining coordinates of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates, boundaries

I created a voronoi polygon using the coordinates shapefile of over 3,000 enumeration areas. How do I get the boundary coordinates of each of the enumeration areas for mapping purposes?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please expand more what you mean by "boundary coordinates", is this the bounding xy min/max or the xy vertex coordinates?

Comment: the boundary coordinates are meant to guide mappers so that they dont encroach into another enumeration area. so I need like the coordinates for the four corners of each of the polygons

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes
```

then

```
Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Add Geometry Column
```

gives you for each corner node of your polgyons and then adds it's coordinates to your attribute table.

Comment: i have already done that but what i actually need is the coordinates for each of the polygons generated not for the points.

Comment: As I said, leave out the polygon centroid step, but the coordinates obtained are confusing as in you get one coordinate for every corner of your polygon. Oh, forgot a step, I am sorry... updated the post

Comment: i left out the polygon centroid step

Comment: I actually forgot a step, sorry for that. So, now the post is (hopefully) helpful.

Comment: ok, please i am waiting for the post.

Comment: It is there, simply modified ;-)

Answer (score 0):

just use OGRINFO so simple.  ogrinfo -ro -so nameoffile.shp nameoffile
convert a folder of shapefiles into a GeoPackage
OGR2OGR -f "GPKG" name.gpkg folderofshp